# How do we regulate the production of proteins when designing plasmids?

Tags: dna, immunology, coronavirus, plasmids, mrna

I think it should be no surprise that I, as many others, am interested in the new COVID-19 vaccines being developed. In my region of the world there are two mayor candidates. One is mRNA based and one is, as far as I understand, plasmid based.

I have a passable understanding of the mRNA based vaccine.
I also know what a plasmid is, and how it is transferred between cells, but my understanding is otherwise limited.

As far as I understand we want the plasmid to be "unlooped" and grafted onto our target cells DNA. This, as far as I reckon, should enable the cell to produce whatever protein the plasmid coded for. In vaccines this lets us device anti-measures (vague because of my lack of knowledge) against the virus... But, how do we regulate the production of these anti-measures? Can we include a "regulator" for the production in the plasmid, so that the modified cells only produce the proteins when the virus is present? Or do we just let the cells continuously produce the anti-measure proteins, regardless of their necessity?

My main interest here lies in where the permanency of the vaccines induced changes lie. With the mRNA vaccine I understand that the permanency lies in the regulated immune system, with other cells being otherwise unchanged after the mRNA decomposes. Regarding the DNA/plasmid vaccine I'm still unwise.

Thank you for your time, and happy holidays.

Comment: The DNA vaccine does ***not*** "graft onto the target cell's DNA" or change its genome in *any way whatsoever*. That's a common misconception and line of attack for anti-vaxxers, and is completely false. Nothing personal against you, I just wanted to emphasize that fact.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate on what it does do instead? My question stems from the fact that it is hard for me to find information on this subject on the internet, and while I appreciate your negation of my false understanding, it is in not the negation alone I seek but a correction which includes the correct understanding.

Comment: I was waiting for someone who had the time to flesh out a real answer, and I'm still hoping someone does, but the quick and dirty answer is that all expression plasmids have an upstream regulatory sequence (before the protein-coding region starts) that includes one or more promoter elements. These elements attract and bind cellular transcription factors which help initiate transcription of the coding region, which is then translated into protein. Typically this process happens continuously until the plasmid is eventually degraded - it doesn't depend on the presence of virus.